# Is Stack Overflow the place to ask about the "goals of different programming models and languages"?

Tags: discussion

I've read this article many a times and ran in to it again today: [Signs that you're a bad programmer](http://www.yacoset.com/Home/signs-that-you-re-a-bad-programmer)

And the 2nd paragraph is something I've been thinking about a lot recently: 2. Poor understanding of the language's programming model

There's a plethora of programming languages out there, and a lot of programming models. I learned programming in college. With some basic Java, PHP, Javascript and C#. These are all either scripted or OOP.

There are several more models and several more languages that implement those models.

Recently, I first tried out Ruby, and I never got beyond the basic stuff. Make an array, make a string, do substrings, etc...

My main problem was: why was I doing this? Why use a different tool when I already have one. You read so much stuff about how great certain languages are, but I feel I don't understand the goal of Ruby. Or its goals, if it has multiple.

Take PHP for example: you can use it to power websites, but also just to be a script that responds to a server request with some text-data.

Then there's other models. Why do I use them and in what situations? Why prefer them over other models, etc...

I'd like to make a Stack Overflow community question, asking this and then making a accessible list for future reference. Or is this not the place for it?

Answer (score 2):

SO is **definitely not** the place for such a discussion, **nor** is programmers.

I suggest [cstheory](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/) as a suitable place.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that. There are a lot of different subdomains now. Never really bothered checking any of them besides SO, ServerFault, superuser and meta.